# youtube-api 403 usageLimits vs quotaLimit

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

What is the difference between the three dailyLimitExceeded vs userRateLimitExceeded vs quotaLimitExceeded with the Youtube-Data API v3. 
While using the API key , I first found that I was getting the userRateLimitExceeded ,then I got the quotaLimitExceeded and finally the dailyLimitExceeded. 
Should all of these be retried after the PST time as mentioned in the error message or there are various wait times to reattempt. 
I have a quota that is more than 10,000 but I still see these errors daily.

Answer (score 0):

All those errors are described in the [Youtube API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/core_errors#FORBIDDEN)

Comment: But they dont elaborate as they do in the other Google Analytics documentation , none of these errors define further about the throttle rate we should instead apply and wait before retry.